# Is there any way to identify each user in a collection of users by some specific id field in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to create display detials accroding to roomid (comman in some users) but the firebase email and password authenication does not support any other property in firebase authenication.
so how i can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can add properties as you wish for each user

Let's say you have a collection called users each user in this collection can have a field named roomId

Then you can get a user by roomId

See the picture below to see how the structure could go to handle your case

[image: Firebase users collection example]

Now you can get a user by the roomId by doing something like this:

```
const db = admin.firestore()
const snapshot = await db
        .collection('users')
        .where('roomId', '==', roomId)
        .get()
const user = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data())
console.log(`users: ${JSON.stringify(user)}`)
```

Comment: If you use this solution, make sure to tighten your security rules so a user can't read users that aren't in the same chat room. Additionally, keep sensitive personally identifiable information (such as a phone/email) in a separate `privateUserData` collection that only that user can read/write. Both methods mitigate someone just coming along and ripping your entire users collection and spamming your users.

Comment: Thanks, @MoathThawahreh and for helping me out
What are your thoughts on that :
I want to get the manual `roomid` at the time of registration and then create a collection named rooms and insert users according to that room id

Comment: @RishabhMalviya, in this case you need two collection one for the users and you can create another one for rooms, then you can add add the users to the room they belong two with the data you need